# SSL certificate issue on Cloudways WP Installation

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cloudways

I have setup a managed WP install on Google Cloud using Cloudways. I am having issues with my SSL certificate appearing in web browsers. Using SSL checker I can see the SSL is installed https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=thesummer.store
I am using a custom SSL certificate rather than using Let's Encrypt SSL which is integrated into Cloudways. However, even when I use Let's Encrypt I run into the same issue.
Cloudways support put the issue down to cache but that isn't the issue.

I have tried re-doing everything from scratch, cleared caches in different browsers, and tried LetsEncrypt over my custom SSL certificate.

According to SSL checker everything is okay.

Comment: Hi, I am Magento Community Manager at Cloudways. Would you please tell me what is actually the problem? If SSL Checker validates your site with valid SSL, it means everything is good to go!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cloudflare for DNS hosting, you need to switch off the proxy (click on the orange cloud at your DNS), apply again the LetsEncrypt from Cloudways, and after activation of SSL, you can again switch on the cloudflare proxy.

The thing is your IP must directly point to your cloudways server to get your SSL Activated. After activation you can activate your Cloudflare Proxy.